# WordPress :Update all post permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem. I thought wordpress would be smart enough to handle this. Anyways...I am using a static frontpage. Everything is working, but not as I like to have it.

By doing this I hoped that the posts permalink would be like /14122018-post-name.

This `14122018` is post date. and this `post-name` is post title

How can I make this work?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the post permalink be in this format:

```
http://example.com/{DD}{MM}{YYYY}-{post slug}
```

Go to the permalink settings page and in the "Custom Structure" box, enter:

```
/%day%%monthnum%%year%-%postname%
```

Then just click on the "Save Changes" button to save the permalink settings.

**No custom coding is necessary.** :)